# datatables with fixedheader: row click function giving error on fixed cols

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have an on click function storing the row data in the console log

if you click on the first two columns, you'll notice the function returns undefined, however any of the unfrozen columns returns the data object

I know that this has todo with the fact that the fixedcolumns are created in a cloned table, i was wondering if there was any workaround to this?

```
// Server-side processing with object sourced data
var $table;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/ssp/objects.php",
      dom: "<'row'<'col-md-6 'l><'col-md-6 pull-right'>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "first_name" },
            { "data": "last_name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],

    scrollY: "600px",
    scrollX: "100%",
    scrollCollapse: true,
        "pageLength": 5,
  lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50 ], [5, 10, 25, 50]],
  order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    } );

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( $table, {
        leftColumns: 2
    } );  


$table.on("click", "tr",function(){
  var aData = $table.row( this ).data();
  console.log( aData);
  } );  
} );
```

[here is my example code in action](http://live.datatables.net/laxinabe/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fnGetPosition](http://datatables.net/docs/FixedColumns/3.0.0/FixedColumns.html#fnGetPosition) to get information about row index.

From the manual:

> This function is functionally identical to `fnGetPosition` in
>   DataTables, taking the same parameter (TH, TD or TR node) and
>   returning exactly the the same information (data index information).
>   The difference between the two is that this method takes into account
>   the fixed columns in the table, so you can pass in nodes from the
>   master table, or the cloned tables and get the index position for the
>   data in the main table.

Your code needs to be modified as follows:

```
var fc = new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( $table, {
   leftColumns: 2
});  

$table.on("click", "tr", function(){
   var aData = $table.row(fc.fnGetPosition(this)).data();
   console.log(aData);
});
```

See this [example code](http://live.datatables.net/laxinabe/20/edit?js,output) for demonstration.

Comment: I did look forever for that, even asked on their offical forums, and appreciate you finding it, thanks much